# how do i bring a multiline CSV file into single line

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-3.0

I have a requirement to parse a CSV which has a last multiline column and convert it into a single lined CSV.

Example:

```
Name,Department,Team,Task
"Jack","QA","AF","He need to work
He needs to update
He needs to plan"
"Sam","Dev","Retail","He need to work
He needs to update
He needs to plan"
```

The Result expected is:

```
Name,Department,Team,Task
"Jack","QA","AF","He need to work.He needs to update.He needs to plan."
"Sam","Dev","Retail","He need to work.He needs to update.He needs to plan"
```

I need to use PowerShell for this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: is the number of task items predictable? your sample shows 3, but that may be simple coincidence.

Comment: Nopes, the last column is not predictable. It sometimes has few lines and sometimes it goes upto 62 lines.

Comment: And is it possible that the tasks may themselves contain commas?

Comment: Commas would make it confusing. Rather if we could use semicolon, it would be great!!

Answer (score 2):

Ah, now that you have quoted your CSV values, this shouldn't be too difficult.

```
# I have faked the input using a here-string, but in real life, you should use
# $csv = Import-Csv -Path <PATH TO THE CSV FILE>

$csv = @"
Name,Department,Team,Task
"Jack","QA","AF","He need to work
He needs to update
He needs to plan"
"Sam","Dev","Retail","He need to work
He needs to update
He needs to plan"
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

# convert all newlines to a full-stop dot and replace multiple spaces in the Task field to become a single space character
$csv | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Task = $_.Task -replace '[\r?\n]+', '. ' -replace '\s{2,}', ' '
    # if you just want to 'normalize' whitespaces like a browser does, use this instead.
    # $_.Task = $_.Task -replace '\s+', ' '
}
```

Now the `$csv` variable holds this data:

```
Name Department Team   Task                                                 
---- ---------- ----   ----                                                 
Jack QA         AF     He need to work. He needs to update. He needs to plan
Sam  Dev        Retail He need to work. He needs to update. He needs to plan
```

Next, write the updated CSV file using semicolons as delimiter

```
$csv | Export-Csv -Path '<PATH TO THE EXPORTED CSV FILE>' -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'
```

Hope that helps

---

**EDIT**

---

As per your comment, I understand more columns may have newlines in them.
This is the updated script, that will turn any field in the file to a single string if it contains newlines.

```
# Again, I have faked the input using a here-string, but in real life, you should use
# $csv = Import-Csv -Path <PATH TO THE CSV FILE>

$csv = @"
Name,Department,Team,Task
"Jack","QA","AF
XYZ","He need to work
He needs to update
He needs to plan"
"Sam","Dev","Retail
Sales","He need to work
He needs to update
He needs to plan"
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

# get an array of the header names
$headers = $csv[0].PSObject.Properties.name

$csv | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($hdr in $headers) {
        # this regex converts all newlines to a full-stop dot and replaces multiple spaces to become one single space character
        $_.$hdr = $_.$hdr -replace '[\r?\n]+', '. ' -replace '\s{2,}', ' '
        # if you just want to 'normalize' all whitespaces like a browser does, use this instead.
        # $_.$hdr = $_.$hdr -replace '\s+', ' '
    }
}
```

After this, the `$csv` variable holds this data:

> ```
> Name Department Team          Task                                                 
> ---- ---------- ----          ----                                                 
> Jack QA         AF. XYZ       He need to work. He needs to update. He needs to plan
> Sam  Dev        Retail. Sales He need to work. He needs to update. He needs to plan
> ```

Export to a new CSV file as usual:

```
$csv | Export-Csv -Path '<PATH TO THE EXPORTED CSV FILE>' -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ';'
```

Comment: This indeed works. However, i wanted to check on one thing, What if the last two columns of my csv have multilines? Could you please help me with the script to bring it on a single line if my last two columns are multilined

Comment: @AbhishekPandey I have edited my answer so it will process all fields that have multilines. Cheers!